# Wildfly 10 Jsession ID

Tags: java, wildfly

I am migrating application server from JBoss 7.1 to Wildfly 10.1 . After I logout of the application, i am not able to login back because the Cookie set on Client side is having expiry date as Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT, which is in the past. The same thing works pretty well on previous version. My application is built on Struts 1.X. Attached here is my cookie header JSESSIONID=FkzDPhKDq-u6t0eanY9i-vAJv3VQwACYsVVo910I.domain.alias; path=/root; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As an FYI - you're using a toolkit that had it's last release 9 years ago and has been unsupported for 4 years.  But how are you viewing the cookie?  What you're showing looks similar to a session cookie but normally wouldn't have the date info.  However, the fact that it's a zero timestamp makes me think it's the view, not the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, my application from somewhere was securing the cookie explicity and adding it to response. This worked well till JBoss 7.1 but Mozilla- Wildlfl combination could not detect the same and always sent the old one back as a new cookie. Solved it. Thanks for the help.